# Bulk update with JSONField in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-jsonfield

```
whens = [When(pk=x, then=_json['info'][str(x)]) for x in ids]
Clinics.objects.filter(pk__in=ids).update(
  info_json=Case(*whens, output_field=JSONField())
)
```

I want to perform bulk update using Case-When statements for JSONField(). When I do this in a stupid cycle with save() on every iteration everithing works fine. But code above writes me:`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'` saying about second line. I also tried json.loads(), but it didn't work out. What should I do to perform this multiple update?

I am using Python 3.6.3 and Django 1.11.16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the time being you're stuck iterating over the instances and updating them one at a time. However, Django 2.2 will introduce [`bulk_update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) which will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually bulk_update is simple case-when with casting. Here is solution without migrating to Django 2.2

```
field_type = Clinic._meta.get_field('info_json')
whens = [When(pk=x, then=Value(_json['info'][str(x)], output_field=field_type) 
for x in ids]
Clinics.objects.filter(pk__in=ids).update(
  info_json=Cast(Case(*whens, output_field=field_type),output_field=field_type)
)
```

Comment: This yields the same output: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'